# Definition of open sets

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Open ball, centered at $$ x \in U,$$ with radius r is defined as
$$ B_r \left( x\right)=\left\{x' \in U \mid \mathrm{d} \left(x, x' \right)<r \right\}.$$

Definition of an open set:
$$ U \ \mathrm{is \ open.} \Leftrightarrow \forall x\in U: \exists r>0: B_r(x)\subset U$$

My question is: don't all points of U anyway satisfy the latter condition? Since $$ x \in U, $$ the open ball is a collection of elements in U and thus a subset of U.

Comment: Yes, $U$ is open *in $U$* always. However, if $V$ is *subset* of $U$, we also say that $V$ is open *in $U$* if for any $x \in V$ there is $r>0$ for which $B_r(x) \subseteq V$, and in this case $V$ is not always open in $U$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definitions are a bit off. The setting is $(X,d)$, a metric space, and the open ball $B_r(x)$ ofr $x \in X$ and $r>0$ is defined as

$$B_r(x)=\{x' \in X\mid d(x,x,') < r\}$$

(**not** $x \in U$).

Then a subset $U \subseteq X$ is open iff

$$\forall x \in U: \exists r>0: B_r(x) \subseteq U$$

And this defines a topology $\mathcal{T}_d$ on $X$.

You take everything relative to $U$, so as if we're working only in $(U,d)$ and then it's indeed not surprising that $U$ is then open, as the whole set is always in any topology...

Answer (score 0):

Lets take $U=\{x: ||x|_2\leq 1\}$

In this case if you take some point on the edge, for example $x=[1,0]$ if we are on the plane, than you can't find such $r>0$ cause $x+r\cdot[1,0]=[1+r,0]$ which is not in $U$.

In this case $U$ is a close set.

If we had $U=\{x: ||x|_2< 1\}$ it was an open set.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't specify what $U$ is.

To your question: it reads like it can be restated, "Aren't all points of $U$ interior points of $U$?"  This need not be the case, depending on what $U$ is.

Consider the real line as a metric space with the metric induced by the modulus:
$$
d(a, b) = |a - b|.
$$
Now let $U = [0,1]$.  As you can see, not all points of $U$ are interior to $U$: the endpoints $0, 1$ are not.

Finally, let me suggest a definition of "open set" that relies on prose rather than on notation, hence is probabily easier to read and process:

**Definition:**  In a metric space, the *open sets* are exactly those sets that are unions of open balls.

In the above example, $U = [0, 1]$ is not open.